70s/80s book: male character had to keep hair long. Front cover male with massive braid over holding cat
Trying to locate the name of this book. Was my bother’s fave. Had a young male with a cat-like companion. He has long hair he wore in a braid. He observed the frustration of conformity with beauty standards (women were expected/allowed to keep theirs short)

What kind of book was this? A novel? A Manga? What language was it written in?

You could improve this Story-Identification question by going through the checklists here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add. For example, what was the man's name? Why was his companion a walking cat? Was this aimed at adults (with sex 'n' gore) or a younger audience? Was the cat companion his girlfriend or just a chum? What did him and the cat get up to, adventuring, running from a baddie? What was the cat-lady's name? What was her species called?
